# Enable ssl/https tls 1.2 on wamp 2.4

Tags: wamp

Is it possible to enable tls 1.2 on wamp 2.4? how?

Or should I install something else instead of good old wamp 2.4?

I tried to add `SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2` to my virtual host but it still doesn't work.